# dnsmasq sometimes resolves things, sometimes it doesn't

Tags: 12.04, dnsmasq

Trying to resolve:

> nslookup testserverinlocaldns
>
> Server:       127.0.0.1
>
> Address:  127.0.0.1#53
>
> ** server can't find testserverinlocaldns: NXDOMAIN

After 10 seconds everything is ok:

> nslookup testserverinlocaldns
>
> Server:       127.0.0.1
>
> Address:  127.0.0.1#53
>
> Name: testserverinlocaldns.localnet
>
> Address: 192.168.3.8

And the same thing again and again. Sometimes it resolves, sometimes not. When I set resolv.conf to local DNS servers manually - everything is ok. But after reboot it gets back to 127.0.0.1 again.

Answer (score 8):

I have this inside my internal network, and I solved it by disabling the local forwarding nameserver controlled by NetworkManager (dnsmasq).

To do that, you need to edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and comment out the “dns=dnsmasq” line in the "[main]" section.

Open a terminal, and run

`sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

Then make sure that the line

> dns=dnsmasq

is commented out like this:

> `#dns=dnsmasq`

Now, restart network-manager with the following command, and everything should work properly.

> sudo restart network-manager

Comment: it works thatnks!

Comment: Yes, it worked for me as well!  kay, since it worked for you I'd suggest doing him the courtesy of accepting this answer.