# How do I enable DNS caching in the NetworkManager-controlled dnsmasq?

Tags: dns, dnsmasq

Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 uses dnsmasq to perform DNS lookups, but it [is not configured to cache](https://askubuntu.com/a/129573) these results. (I have checked this by using dig to resolve names and I do not see a large improvement in the response time after the first lookup.) How do I configure the NetworkManager-controlled dnsmasq to cache the results of DNS lookups?

Answer (score 11):

In Ubuntu 12.10 you can enable the cache of the NetworkManager-controlled dnsmasq instance by putting the line

```
cache-size=1000
```

(with your preferred number of names instead of 1000) in a new file in `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/`.  To activate this change you must then do

```
sudo stop network-manager
sudo killall dnsmasq
sudo start network-manager
```

or reboot.

Comment: Thank you for your info.  For Ubuntu 16.04 (and 15.10 since systemd was introduced), use "sudo service network-manager stop/start" rather than "sudo stop/start network-manager"

Comment: Although that still works, using the systemd tool it should be: `sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager`

Answer (score 4):

I was able to enable DNS caching in Linux Mint 13 (based on Ubuntu 12.04) using the method described in the first answer.  I created a file `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/cachedns` containing the line `cache-size=100`, then restarted network-manager.  Even though dnsmasq is executed by network-manager with a hard-coded `--cache-size=0` on its command line, setting the cache-size in a config file overrides that value.  You can verify that it works by doing this:

```
sudo killall -USR1 dnsmasq
tail /var/log/syslog
```

You should see a line that looks like this in the syslog, showing the cache size:

```
dnsmasq[17808]: cache size 100, 0/2 cache insertions re-used unexpired cache entries.
```

Comment: I wondered how network-manager's hard-coded --cache-size=0 was affected, but your post makes me clear.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

in 12.04 dnsmasq is started by NetworkManager with hard-coded (i.e. not configurable) parameter **--cache-size=0**.

manpages for dnsmasq says setting cache-size to zero disables caching. If you want to enable caching, you will probably have to disable the dnsmasq-plugin for NetworkManager to prevent NetworkManager from starting dnsmasq and start your own instance of dnsmasq with cache-size greater then zero.

here you can read how to disable dnsmasq-plugin for NetworkManager: https://askubuntu.com/a/131422/71057

Answer (score 1):

I didn't want to upgrade from 12.04, but still wanted dnsmasq managed by NetworkManager with caching enabled, but as the other answer said, --cache-size=0 is hard-coded and can't be changed with configuration.

So what I ended up doing was the following, as root:

```
mv /usr/sbin/dnsmasq /usr/sbin/dnsmasq.real
```

and then creating a new file, /usr/sbin/dnsmasq with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
args=$(echo "$@" | sed 's/--cache-size=0/--cache-size=1000/')
/usr/sbin/dnsmasq.real $args
```

make sure you `chmod +x /usr/sbin/dnsmasq`, and change the cache-size from 1000 to whatever you want, enjoy your LTS release with a DNS cache!

Answer (score 1):

To re-enable the cache (with a NetworkManager version that has the /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d directory), it is actually sufficient to drop a file in that directory with content "cache-size=X" (with X being 150 for the default dnsmasq would have). The files in there override the hard-coded parameters given on the commandline.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 14.04, I had to edit `/etc/default/dnsmasq` and set `ENABLED=1`

I also put `cache-size=1000` there and in all the other dnsmasq config files that I found.